# Firebase database - insert record in sequence - Android

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

How to store record in sequence like NUMBER_1,NUMBER_2,NUMBER_3,NUMBER_4,NUMBER_5,NUMBER_6,NUMBER_7,NUMBER_8,NUMBER_9,NUMBER_10,NUMBER_11 and so on, right now its like attached image.. how to store and get record in proper sequence. thanks in advance

here how i insert records

```
for (int i = 1; i <= Integer.parseInt(enteredNumber); i++) {
            NumberModel numberModel = new NumberModel(i, true, "");
            DatabaseReference numberRef = mDatabase.child("room").child(roomId);
            numberRef.child("total_numbers").child("NUMBER_" + i).setValue(numberModel);
        }
```

Comment: The records are already in proper order. these are sorted alphabetically in ascending order

Comment: is there any way to store or get record in NUMBER_1,NUMBER_2,NUMBER_3,NUMBER_4,NUMBER_5,NUMBER_6,NUMBER_7,NUMBER_8,NUMBER_9,NUMBER_10,NUMBER_11 and so on, this order?

Comment: There is way to get record in sorted order. About storing it is dependent on you how you code.

Comment: store data using for loop. please check edited question.